How to pass specific list of files to fzf and ripgrep
I have been recently discovering the combination of fzf and ripgrep and it is working just fine.
ww(){
  export BAT_THEME='gruvbox-dark'
  RG_PREFIX="rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case "
  INITIAL_QUERY="${*:-}"
  : | fzf --ansi --disabled --query "$INITIAL_QUERY" \
      --bind "start:reload:$RG_PREFIX {q}" \
      --bind "change:reload:sleep 0.1; $RG_PREFIX {q} || true" \
      --bind "alt-enter:unbind(change,alt-enter)+change-prompt(2. fzf> )+enable-search+clear-query" \
      --color "hl:-1:underline,hl+:-1:underline:reverse" \
      --prompt '1. ripgrep> ' \
      --delimiter : \
      --preview 'bat --color=always {1} --highlight-line {2}' \
      --preview-window 'up,60%,border-bottom,+{2}+3/3,~3' \
      --bind 'enter:become(lvim {1} +{2})'
}

However, the use case for me is really to pass specific list of files that I put together based them into this function above ?
echo /path/to/file1 /another/path/file2 ... | \
  export BAT_THEME='gruvbox-dark'
  RG_PREFIX="rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case "
  INITIAL_QUERY="${*:-}"
  : | fzf --ansi --disabled --query "$INITIAL_QUERY" \
      --bind "start:reload:$RG_PREFIX {q}" \
      --bind "change:reload:sleep 0.1; $RG_PREFIX {q} || true" \
      --bind "alt-enter:unbind(change,alt-enter)+change-prompt(2. fzf> )+enable-search+clear-query" \
      --color "hl:-1:underline,hl+:-1:underline:reverse" \
      --prompt '1. ripgrep> ' \
      --delimiter : \
      --preview 'bat --color=always {1} --highlight-line {2}' \
      --preview-window 'up,60%,border-bottom,+{2}+3/3,~3' \
      --bind 'enter:become(lvim {1} +{2})'

Any ideas ?
